# How to inject Grails services into src/groovy classes

Tags: grails, dependency-injection

Grails 2.4.x here. If I created a Grails service using `grails create-service com.example.Widget`, then how can I inject a reference of that service (a "bean") into a class under `src/groovy`?

This is actually not explained anywhere in the official Grails docs, and extensive searching turned back nadda.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**1)** You can use Spring Beans to inject a service into a non-artefact groovy file, using `resources.groovy`:

**MyClass.groovy**

```
class MyClass {
    def widgetService
    ...
}
```

**resources.groovy**

```
beans = {
    myclass(com.example.MyClass) {
        widgetService = ref('widgetService')
    }
}
```

**2)** There is also an additional `@Autowired` annotation that can do the same thing:

**MyClass.groovy**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired

class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    def widget
    ...
}
```

**resources.groovy**

```
beans = {
    myclass(com.example.MyClass) {}
}
```

Notice - this time the `myclass` bean doesn't need the reference to the `widget`.

**3)** There is an alternative to injecting the `WidgetService` - using the `Holders` class to get the `grailsApplication` which will have a reference to the existing bean.

```
import grails.util.Holders

class MyClass {
    def widgetService = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('widgetService')

    ...
}
```

****Update****

**4)** There is another option that is a hybrid of 1) and 2) -
Having the bean(s) injected by `autowire=true` within **resources.groovy**:

**MyClass.groovy**

```
class MyClass {
    def widgetService
    ...
}
```

**resources.groovy**

```
beans = {
    myclass(com.example.MyClass) { bean ->
        bean.autowire = true
    }
}
```

This is the approach I've been using locally as I feel it's the cleanest, but it does take more advantage of Grail's 'magic' (for better or worse).

Comment: Thanks @tylerwal (+1) however Option #3 (my preferred solution) produces an exception when I do a `grails run-app`: `Error loading Config.groovy: Cannot get property 'mainContext' on null object`...any ideas?!?

Comment: Also Option #1 still results with `widgetService` being null inside `MyClass` at runtime.

Comment: In your other question, you have a constructor defined on your `FizzBuzzer` class with a `statsService` argument, Grails uses Field Injection so you can remove this unless you plan on not using dependency injection and instantiating the `FizzBuzzer` yourself with the necessary service.

Comment: Also, Grails uses convention over configuration, therefore I would rename `statsService` to `statisticsService` within your Groovy class to avoid any potential problems involving a mismatching name - although if you use `resources.groovy` and an explicit `ref()` this shouldn't matter.

Comment: I can throw a toy project showing all 3 ways of getting the service on github later tonight if the issue remains.

Comment: Thanks @tylerwal (+3 for each comment!) - I think I may be on to something here: **When does Grails inject these beans: *before* or *after* `Bootstrap#init` executes?** If they happen *after* `Bootstrap#init`, then I've solved my problem: I'm invoking `MyClass` methods inside `Boostrap#init`, and so Grails hasn't had a chance to inject `MyClass` with a valid `WidgetService` yet. Thoughts?!?

Comment: OK @tylerwal I've confirmed, `Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('widgetService')` works when I reference it after the app has already started up. **However**, when I try to reference it from a method called directly from `Bootstrap#init`, the `grailsApplication` is NULL, which explains the exception in my first comment up above. So now the problem at hand is: **How do I access the `WidgetService` bean from inside `Bootstrap.groovy#init`?**

Comment: Looks like [this *might* work](http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/16/getting-spring-beans-in-grails-bootstrap/) although I'm not sure what would be required to extract a `widgetService` bean of type `com.example.myapp.WidgetService` out of that `sprintContext` variable...

Comment: OK got it, just had to do `springContext.getBean('widgetService')`! Boom! Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Normal Grails dependency injection `def WidgetService` within Bootstrap should work by itself.

Comment: The option #3 works for me. I don't really understand how it cannot work with the option #2. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I used the first option, but I realized that if I use the `class` name istead of `def` didnt work