# Grails 3.X Inject service into Custom Listener

Tags: grails, service, listener

i wonder if someone knows hot to inject a service into a custom listener in Grails 3.X. I'm working with spring secuirty plugin in order to avoid brut force attacks. There is one answer but for Grails 2.0. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE !
Just for those who can use it . I tried Autowired and it works. Something like:

@Autowired
public LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService

The LoginAttemptService is already declared as a Bean

Answer (score 0):

As [shown here](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/wschat/WsChatEndpoint.groovy)
Declare it like your injection:

```
 MyService myService
```

Then when needed

```
 def ctx = Holders.applicationContext
 myService= ctx.myService
```

Alternatively

```
def myService = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('myService')
```

The alternate method is particulary useful for src/main/groovy calls if required to a service

Think their both the same thing in different ways

Comment: Thanks, i've tried those but the app doesn't recognize Holders (working with Grails 3.2). I tried Autowired and it works!, something like this:   @Autowired
private LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService                                The service is already declared as a Bean. Regards.

Comment: I guess what you said had me curious, @Autowired isn't something new.  http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/grails-goodness-injecting-grails.html  (2013) and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427697/how-to-inject-grails-services-into-src-groovy-classes. Which then made me wonder maybe your listener is working differently to a socket listener.